# How to select only the row who contains more information

Tags: mysql

Mysql Version 5.5.62

I have a table

3,24481,356146

24481,356146

3,356146

3

24481

and i want to get this result

3,24481,356146

only the row who contains all the others row's values.

Let me explain better what i need. I am migranting my way of doing a similar products relation.

currently my releantion is product by product in this way

```
id_prod                  id_prod_sim1                 id_prod_sim2        

3                        24481                        356146

24481                    3                            356146

356146                   24481
```

and how you can see has a 'error' in the relation because in the row of id_prod 356146 the id 3 is not related, and I have more examples, so the solution of the lenght is not correct

but now I want to take all the products who have relation and put they in a group.

by doing a select I arrive in the result of the post.

the select is that

```
select 
   b.*
from (select 
      a.cd_produto,
      GROUP_CONCAT(a.cd_similar order by a.cd_similar) as similares
from
(
select
    p.Codigo as cd_produto,
    p.Codigo as cd_similar
from prodserv_dados p
union all
select 
    p.codigo as cd_produto,
    p.`Prod_Similar_1` as cd_similar
from prodserv_dados p
where p.`Prod_Similar_1` <> 0
union all
select 
    p.codigo as cd_produto,
    p.`Prod_Similar_2`
from prodserv_dados p
where p.`Prod_Similar_2` <> 0
union all
select 
    p.codigo as cd_produto,
    p.`Prod_Similar_3`
from prodserv_dados p
where p.`Prod_Similar_3` <> 0
) a 
group by a.cd_produto
having cast(a.cd_produto as char) <> GROUP_CONCAT(a.cd_similar order by 
a.cd_similar)) b
group by b.similares order by b.cd_produto
```

Comment: Imagine that you have 3 rows with the values (1,2), (1,3) and (2,3). What output do you need in this case?

Comment: In my case always will have a row with the value(1,2,3), beyond the values (1,2),(1,3) and (2,3). And I want the value(1,2,3)

Comment: *In my case always will have a row with the value(1,2,3),* If so then simply select the row with maximal length. `.. ORDER BY LENGTH(column) DESC LIMIT 1`.

Comment: Please do it in the question - edit/update it. Also specify **precise** MySQL version - it can be important.

Comment: I did the modifications